# Easy to use CCK?

Tags: joomla-3.x, cck

Is there an easy to use CCK out there that a newbie can try and not get discouraged? I tested a market leader and my brain fried. Two hours and nothing to show for it. I need something with a form front-end to create an application (for our little neighborhood association).

Comment: Its not a duplicate. I'm asking about an easy to use CCK here.

Comment: The problem I've seen with CCK's, is that they try to be one of two products.  Either they try to do it all, or they try to skeleton the output so you have just barely what you need.  People who have little to no PHP experience tend to go for the overwhelming products, because they don't want to waste a lot of time trying to program the rest of their simple 2 view component.  There are a lot of good examples in the answers/comments here, but take it all with a grain of salt.  You're getting answers from people who probably know what they're doing.

Answer (score 5):

To add more Joomla! CCKs to the list:

- **Cobalt** Cobalt 8 opens incredible possibilities for constructing websites, and allows you to build almost anything. http://www.mintjoomla.com/joomla-components/cobalt.html
- **Joomla Component Creator** - Develop and learn MVC the easy way http://www.component-creator.com/en/
- **Fabrik** - Flexible Joomla! content creation http://fabrikar.com/
- **FLEXIcontent** - Advanced CCK for Joomla! (similar to K2) http://www.flexicontent.org/
- **Zoo** ZOO is a flexible and powerful content application builder to manage your content. http://yootheme.com/zoo/downloads#free

Answer (score 3):

Typically, you gotta do a chunk of set up to make a CCK usable on the client side, so you do need to have some development skills to get it going. Here's some stuff I can tell you:

I have not used **Fabrik**, yet, but I have heard nothing but good stuff, and it seems to be the simplest of the CCKs, though again, if you want crazy functionality, you need to be able to get into the code.
 // **AMENDMENT ** I have since used Fabrik and found it to be nothing but an exercise in frustration. I do not recommend it unless you are using it strictly for tables and rows of data.

**ContentBuilder** - I have used this, and I am not a huge fan, but it is more toggles and switches orientated than it is development orientated, so it might be an option for you.

**K2** - this is a huge component, with a ton of expandability, I've used it extensively. If you want to go straight out of the box, you'll be okay. As soon as you want to 'move this extra field over here' you need to get into the php and template overrides.

**Sobipro** - this is my current go-to for CCKs - It's not as intuitive as I'd like, for development, but if you're just flipping toggles and switches, you'll be okay. This one depends heavily on code if you want to customize the output.

Comment: Did you ever try SEBLOD?  It may be more towards developers.

Comment: I haven't. As a company we have moved away from Joomla though, so likely not to explore it.

Answer (score 3):

I tend to use **ChronoForms** rather than a CCK but would not describe ChronoForms as easy for a beginner.

From a recent Joomla Beat podcast, I get the impression from **Chad Windnagle** that the simplest and most future proof CCK would be a plugin that doesn't interfere with the core code. By "future proof", I mean something that's easy to upgrade or migrate from one version of Joomla to another. From what I understand, some CCKs made Joomla 1.5 to 2.5 migrations very difficult.

Searching JED, the closest existing match seems to be **Aixeena CCK** http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/authoring-a-content/content-construction/27155 which apparently stores data on the default attributes or parameters without needing to install any new tables or fields so that data can be used on every front-end component, module, plugin or template.

I haven't used Aixeena CCK yet but it might be worth a try.

Comment: Excellent suggestion - I've used it myself and it's very nice to rely on the core code, rather than 3rd party code, for maintaining it.  Not so fun if you need that data in SQL statements, but for day to day stuff, outSTANDing.

Comment: There's another one which is more powerful than Aixeena CCK but still simple: Fields Attach. http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/authoring-a-content/content-construction/18564 It follows the same principle, but it's a bit richer in features. If you just need simple stuff, Aixeena CCK is perfect.

Comment: Content Builder maps the core code and SEBLOD also can use the core code.  I found SEBLOD was limited, but Content Builder claims to allow content plugins and everything else.

Answer (score 3):

I highly suggest ZOO.  It is probably the most user friendly but still looks professional.  There is a submissions function that maps to the data type in the backend which is very slick.

You can most likely use the free version using the PAGE type.  http://yootheme.com/zoo/

If you have a specific thing to setup, I can probably point you in the right direction.

Comment: Yes! Zoo is the best and very flexible option.

Answer (score 3):

**Complicated CCKs which can do a lot**

I have tried K2, but had no real requirement to extend it. It's very easy to use out of the box.

I have tried SEBLOD for a highly customised app.  I found it confusing, the language didn't make much sense, and I found the support lacking (you have the option to pay for further support).  Given the delay in the support, and some of the glitches, I don't think I will use it on a commercial site again.  They also miss deadlines for updates.

[Fabrik](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/fabrik) is another highly complicated app, but you can do a lot with it.

[Content Builder](https://crosstec.org) looks promising I will try that next.  It looks as powerful as SEBLOD but integrates well with the core, allows content plugins, and seems to be named in a more user friendly way so you can guess where you need to be.

**Easier CCKs which just add fields**

[DP Fields](https://joomla.digital-peak.com/) is going to be added to the core in the next minor update, and is a really good add on that uses the core.  It allows you to add extra fields to the core (they appear within tabs in articles), but it gets quite basic if you want to really expand Joomla.  It's great for beginners.  I would say this is the easiest.

Fields Attach is similar, but I would recommend the above as it is due to become part of the core.

**Doing it manually is not that hard!!!**

You could always extend Joomla! yourself.  It is intended to be reasonably easy to do so.  https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_core_components_using_a_plugin
https://zunostudios.com/blog/development/203-how-to-add-custom-fields-to-articles-in-joomla

Overall, creating additional fields in Joomla is very easy.  Displaying them is slightly harder and may be where you find a CCK to be a good use.  If you just want to add additional fields to registration, you probably just want to extend.

**Built into Joomla**
As per this post and Lodder. [How to display user profile information?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/899/how-to-display-user-profile-information)

There is a in User Profile plugin that comes with Joomla. In the Joomla backend, go to

Extensions (top menu) >> Plugin Manager >> User Profile.

You will see the following custom fields:

Address 1
Address 2
City Region
Country
Postal / ZIP Code
Phone
Web site
Favourite Book
About Me
Date of Birth

You can choose which ones you want on the registration and profile page.

Here is an excellent article explaining how to display certain information.  [How to display user profile information?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/899/how-to-display-user-profile-information)

Answer (score 2):

Check out **RSform Pro** (http://www.rsjoomla.com/joomla-extensions/joomla-form.html) You have the ability to to populate fields with values taken from an external table or from any Joomla table.

You can also get an email with PDF of the application once submitted if you like. This can be sent to any number of emails or your Google Drive account?

This extension also allows for custom php scripting such as scripts called on form display / on form process / after form process. So you have the option of writing your own functions and embedding these within your form, alternatively there are a number of plugins that come with the pro version - http://www.rsjoomla.com/support/documentation/view-knowledgebase/26-plugins-and-modules.html

The only one I'm not sure about is Number 4 on your list - Save on next.

Regarding the re-direct there are also plugins available for this such as http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/login-redirect

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good suggestion, but I'm actually looking for a CCK.

Comment: Fabrik does it all but can be very difficult to understand i found

Answer (score 2):

I think Seblod CCK is the best Joomla CCK out there and built by guys that have large customers like Pegout, General Electrics etc

Here is the link to Seblod CCK!  http://www.seblod.com/

**Build high-end websites with Joomla!**
**Outclass Drupal with < Joomla! + SEBLOD**

*SEBLOD is an Application Builder and a Content Construction Kit.
It helps to create/manage custom online applications & full-featured websites.*

**Sites made with Joomla! + SEBLOD.**

SEBLOD is used by some high-end companies for its performance & flexibility.

**General Electric**
- Digital Asset Management
- InContext Front-end Editing
- Multi-sites Platform

**Alain Milliat**

**Peugeot Assurance**

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised that I haven't seen [Form2Content CCK](http://www.form2content.com/) in any of the lists yet. A relative low learning curve and has good and simple front-end management options. Article templating using Smarty provides flexibility for "dynamic" effects like default image or text.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my "CCK" suggestions. Ordering is from simplicity/easiness to complex.

1. FieldsAttach (limited, but extends J! core articles and categories)
2. K2 (v3 is coming before Xmas)
3. Cobalt v8 (most versatile in regards of field types and possible workflows and applications, at first sight complex but easy to understand)

I assume, your initial post and experience is probably with Seblod CCK!? It is definitely not for everyone! i.e. the average Joomla user or hobby sitebuilder.

Answer (score 0):

The best CCK for Joomla i can suggest you is: **King Content**

It's FREE and it help to build almost kind of content site.

It supports extra fields and you can assign an article to many categories, strongly support SEO/SEF and the interface is much like com_content, so it's very easy to use if you familiar with core joomla content.

JED link: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/authoring-a-content/content-construction/king-content

Download: http://www.joomultra.com/download/extensions/king-content.html

Comment: I found bugs here and it doesn't appear to be being developed any more.  The forum was full of toot and I didn't get an answer.  Although it is quite powerful and feature rich.

Answer (score 0):

A new and easy to use CCK : **JBuildozer** : http://www.jbuildozer.com
You can create custom apps and modules for Joomla 3.x. You can create custom fields and much more.

It's not free but it’s worth it ! I find it very easy.

Answer (score 0):

I tried lot of CCKs for Joomla. I used K2 for years but to create complex sites and functions it's not enough. My personal favorite and the only one what I can suggest is **Cobalt 8**. This CCK is more an application builder with endless possibilities. You can do almost everything but I think it's not for beginners. On the official forum you can get help from the community.

Cobalt 8: http://www.mintjoomla.com/joomla-components/cobalt.html