# Content type with own fields and form

Tags: content, cck, seblod

I am a Drupal developer and now I am trying to create web using Joomla.

What I need to do:

- Create new content type "Product"
- Create few fields to content types - e.g. price
- Create order form which is visible only on Product pages

  - Text field in form with default value - actual url

What is the best way and best plugins to accomplish these tasks?

I have tried Seblod - I can create new content types, fields and forms but I don't know how to show the form just on product pages.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you want a seblod or another CCK solution? FLEXIcontent CCK: http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/flexicontent

Comment: May I suggest http://www.component-creator.com/en/?
It offers you many fields: https://docs.joomla.org/Form_field and foreignkeys to other tables.

Comment: iamrobert: Flexicontent looks fine. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at these questions: [**CCK and App Builders**](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/14567/joomlas-extension-for-a-custom-database-application/14569#14569) and [**Easy to use CCK**](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5550/easy-to-use-cck)

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for a CCK extension and there are plenty of free and paid options available:

http://extensions.joomla.org/category/authoring-a-content/content-construction

A forms extension such (e.g. ChronoForms) may work equally well in this case:

http://extensions.joomla.org/category/contacts-and-feedback/forms

Custom Fields will be added to Joomla in version 3.7 which is due for imminent release.

Answer (score 1):

I reviewed this question as it was "bumped to the homepage by Community" ... and felt that we certainly have to mention now the new Joomla core feature of custom fields (`com_fields`) that allows to extend Joomla core components and potentially 3rd party ones, with custom fields.

So even the core articles could be turned to products content items.