# Joomla's extension for a custom database application

Tags: joomla-3.x, extensions, extension-request

I need to create a website which will basically feature a database with a lot of records. Each user can see a big list of every record and then a page dedicated with all the informations about it. I need something like this:

http://redump.org/discs/system/ps2/

With maybe some cool feature like instant search in the list and so on. I've tried to search on google but I really don't know which keyword to use, because if I use "joomla database module" of course I'll get a lot of false pages talking about the Joomla's database. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if you understand exactly what is a module, but definetelly that is not the type of extension you need, although, you haven't specified exactly what exactly you need, but looking at the site you linked, it seems you need a **Custom Application**. That could be a **custom [component](https://docs.joomla.org/Component)**, or a **database app** -built with special extensions called **application builders**.

## Custom Component or Form/DB Application

#### 1. Custom Component

Develop a **custom component** according to your requirements. Component is the type of extension you need, where you will have your datbase tables to store the data, forms to submit/edit information, and all the app logic and its presentation in front-end, back-end or both.

#### 2. Application Builder

Build the application using an [**Application/Form builder**](https://www.google.gr/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=joomla%20application%20builder%20JED&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=TrhiVre8BIuEUPyKgaAM), or [**CCK (content construction) component**](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension?searchall=&filter%5Btags%5D%5B%5D=&filter%5Bcore_catid%5D=209&filter%5Bincludes%5D=&filter%5Bversions%5D=&filter%5Btype%5D=&filter%5Bhasdemo%5D=&order=&filter%5Bnewupdated%5D=&filter%5Bscore%5D=&filter%5Bfavourites%5D=&dir=DESC&limitstart=0&controller=filter&view=extension&layout=list&Itemid=145&clearorders=0&clearfilters=1). A 3rd extensions type option is [**Directory Builders**](http://extensions.joomla.org/tags/directory) depending on your needs.

I distinguish these categories extensions above, although they are very similar and many extensions that fall into any of these categories can be considered or used as CCK's, Application/Form or Directory Builders.

However in many cases CCKs and Directory Builders can provide a more established base and workflow, that you can use and extend with custom fields, while on Application Builders you will have to design everything from scratch.

### Which way to go?

Now regarding the 2 options above, **developing a custom component** requires good development skills and experience. However there are some extension builder tools available that can help you develop your extension (see list below).
Building the application with another **CCK/App Builder application** can be easier - although there is still some learning curve and depending on your actual requirements, good skills might be required as well.

In Both cases when we talk about a database app, you need to plan and design upfront - before the implementation.

#### Component Development Documentation

- [Developing a MVC Component](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component)
- [What tools can I use to help assist me with Joomla development?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/12143/what-tools-can-i-use-to-help-assist-me-with-joomla-development/12154#12154).

#### Component/Extension Creators:

- [Component Creator](https://www.component-creator.com/en/)
- [jDeveloper](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/miscellaneous/development/jdeveloper)
- [Component Builder](http://www.mmleoni.net/joomla-component-builder)
- [j-Cook](http://www.j-cook.pro)

#### Some popular Application/Form Builders & CCKs:

- [Fabrik](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/contacts-and-feedback/forms/fabrik)
- [Cobalt](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/authoring-a-content/content-construction/cobalt)
- [Content Builder](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/authoring-a-content/content-construction/contentbuilder)
- [Seblod](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/authoring-a-content/content-construction/seblod)
- [K2](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/authoring-a-content/content-construction/k2)
- [Sobi Pro](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/directory-a-documentation/directory/sobipro)

Comment: Couldn't ask for anything better, thank you! If you have any suggestion to edit the title (module seems inappropriate) please tell me

Answer (score 0):

I'd be looking first at the ready made list/directory/download apps such as JB Catalog which might be best suited out of the box for your application. Sobi Pro might be a very quick solution for your needs too.

Otherwise review the others apps listed by @FFrewin such as Fabrik, Cobalt, Content Builder, Seblod, K2, which are very flexible and feature rich.

They support various forms of import as well which could save you a lot of time in content setup.