# Joomla learning extension

Tags: joomla-3.x, development, plugin, extensions, extension-request

I am looking for an independent platform, or an "extension" for joomla, that has or allows to develop the following characteristics:

Role 'Student' - This has a personal page where you will be presented with 'topics' for each lesson you had, and within that topic there could be videos, images, text, etc.

Role 'Teacher' - This could 'access' any student's page and create the topics mentioned above, and add to it several types of media, also referred to above.

Role 'Administrator' - That deals with everything that is configuration and maintenance of the platform. From creating new accounts and assigning roles, to modifying the look.

Can you help me?

Thank you!

ps .: I've been seeing the moodle platform, but it's not quite what I want, since in moodle, the teacher adds content and several students have access to it.
What I want is for the teacher to add independent content to each student.

Comment: If such an extension exists, you'd probably find it in the JED with the "learning management system" tag: https://extensions.joomla.org/tags/lms

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is an extension with the exact features you want - but certainly, you can [**develop a custom component**](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component). This, of course, requires some experience and knowledge.

There is also a [**component-creator platform**](https://www.component-creator.com/) that helps developing components faster.

You could also go with **Application Builders/CCKs**, read here: **[Joomla's extension for a custom database application](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/14567/joomlas-extension-for-a-custom-database-application)**

Answer (score 1):

In Moodle the teacher can add content so that just one student has access to it. So Moodle can do what you want but you need to learn how to administer courses. I recommend you go through the [Learn Moodle MOOC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EBFilrURy2Y&index=28&list=PLxcO_MFWQBDdYwQYp5VBtOWn9xDTJV6kZ) videos on YouTube.

There are 2 great solutions for you and they are [iGuru] which is well developed and very easy to use and [OSCampus from Joomlashack] which is also very easy to use.