# How Can I Add Custom User Fields To the User Manager?

Tags: joomla-3.3.x, user, user-groups, joomla-user-groups

I would like to add custom user fields such as: address, phone, etc to the User Manager section of my Joomla! installation for each of my current, as well as, new users that I setup on my website – so that I can use that data throughout the website.  How can I go about correctly setting this up?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is pretty well described at this question/answer.  http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/899/how-to-display-user-profile-information/901#901

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Joomla also provides a plugin named `User-Profile` using which you can maintain additional user related information.

This plugins is pre-installed with joomla installation.

In case this plugin is not sufficient enough to handle your requirement then you can either modify this extension to collect more information or you can create similar extension.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Component->Community builder->Field management.

There you can choose which kind of field you want to create. After that you can asign him to a tab you want. If you want to create your own tab, you to first go to the Tab Management (Component->Community builder->Tab management)

Comment: This assumes that Community Builder is installed.