# How to Access User-Profile Component Data via PHP

Tags: component, php, user, access

I am using Joomla! v3.3.3 and I have just enabled the "User-Profile" component.

How can I access and/or echo the "User-Profile" component data via PHP, such as: address1, city, website, etc?

I know how to access/echo standard user data ex. `<?php echo $user->username; ?>` but how can I access and echo out the "User-Profile" component's data?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else with this question, you can find the answer here: [How to display user profile information?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/899/how-to-display-user-profile-information/901#901)

As described in the aforementioned post, the short answer is as follows:

**To access the User Profile Data**

```
jimport( 'joomla.user.helper' ); 
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$userId = $user->id; 
$userProfile = JUserHelper::getProfile( $userId );

echo "Main Address: " . $userProfile->profile['address1']
```